# scrollVert doesnt work with fit: true jqCycle

Tags: jquery, transition, cycle

I'm using jQuery Cycle for my website.
I would like to use the transition scrollVert and make my slideshow responsive. It works with transitions like 'fade'. But with the vertical scroll or other transitions nothing is displayed. It had something to do with the fit:1 option. If I remove this and remove all other options that makes my slideshow reponsive the transition is working fine. But I need to make a responsive slideshow, so is there a solution for this?

```
$('#slider').cycle({ 
    fx:    'scrollVert',
    slideResize: true,
    containerResize: false,
    width: '100%',
    fit: 1
});
```

http://inspired.xeption.nl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution

http://jsfiddle.net/dVf8V/4/

```
<script src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.scrollVert.js"></script>
```

It is using version 2 of cycle